# how to select the first td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Html is bellow.

```
<tr class="success">
    cfgdfgh
<td>1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>
<input class="btn btn-mini btn-danger deleteMenu" type="button" value="Delete" name="delete">fgfg</td>
</tr>
```

My Jquery code is bellow

```
    $(".deleteMenu").click(function(){    
$(this).parent().css("color","red");
    });
```

I tried that using above jquery code but no luck.I want to selete first td ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/u4A7V/)

Comment: What's going on? Does this question need 10 answers?

Comment: hehe it looks like we all tried to answer it at the same time.  oh well  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').css("color", "red");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u4A7V/9/)**

With your selector, `.parent()`, you're selecting the cell that contains the button. One way to accomplish what you want it to traverse up the DOM to the row (`.closest('tr')`) and then back down to the first cell (`.find('td:first')`).

BTW on a side note, in your example, the text `cfgdfgh` isn't valid where you have it.

Comment: It might be better to use `closest` rather than `parents`, since `closest` will only return one result while `parents` could return multiple (for example, if there are nested tables)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easily done this way:

```
$(".parentClass").find("td:eq(0)")... /* :eq(0) = first occurance */
```

Also your HTML Markup is erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

1) Start by writing valid HTML

2) Go up the DOM tree until u get to the row element, for that you should use .closest()

3) Find the first child of that row element

4) Apply whatever style changes you want

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4A7V/7/

Code:

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr") // go up the tree
      .find("td:first-child") // find the first child
      .css("color", "red"); // change color
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to assign a class to the .  I don't know if it's possible to assign an id to a  (probably possible).

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first `td` in the row:

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function(){    
    $('.success td').eq(0).css("color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefull this helps:

http://jsbin.com/eruric/1/edit

```
$(".success").find("td:first").css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid, you lack a '' tag and you have text outside the `<td>`s, change it to this:

```
<table>
<tr class="success">
<td>1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>home1</td>
<td>
<input class="btn btn-mini btn-danger deleteMenu" type="button" value="Delete" name="delete">fgfg</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and then your js to:

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function(){    
    $(this).parent().siblings(':eq(0)').css("color","red");
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/xZCrk/)

Answer (score 1):

Here we are:

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function(){    
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().css("color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".deleteMenu").parent()` will choose the parent of that input, which is the TR. Also, don't include code straight in the TR, use TD or TH and put it inside. So after putting it in its own TD, you're looking for

```
$(".deleteMenu").click(function(){    
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().css("color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first-child`.

I assume `myTable` is an Id of table

```
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").css("color","red");
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4A7V/8/)

Please change your markup as well.

`tr` elements can only have `td` no `text`. You have write text in `tr` element.